# Replace Unicode numeral subscript or superscript with plain numeral

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, superscript, unicode-normalization

How do I replace a Unicode numeral subscript or superscript (eg, `₂`) with the corresponding numeral (ie, `2`) using regular expressions? I can of course replace each of them separately, but that is ten lines of code...

I am implementing this in Perl but that should not really matter.

Comment: how about just using `ord` function, e.g. ₂ (u2802) => 50

Comment: `$x =~ tr/1234/abcd/ # convert 1 → a, 2 → b, 3 → c, 4 → d `

Comment: When I do this $x =~ tr/₂₃/23/, something simple as CO₂ is converted into CO233.

Comment: As I already mentioned in a comment to tchrist's answer, adding `use utf8` makes `tr/₂₃/23/` work correctly for strings defined in the Perl script. Adding `use open qw[:std IO :utf8]` makes it also work for strings read in from other sources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here from [the *unisupers* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unisupers) is a Perl function to convert to Unicode superscripts:

```perl
sub convert_to_superscripts (_) {
   my $string = $_[0];
   $string =~ tr[+−=()0123456789AaÆᴂɐɑɒBbcɕDdðEeƎəɛɜɜfGgɡɣhHɦIiɪɨᵻɩjJʝɟKklLʟᶅɭMmɱNnɴɲɳŋOoɔᴖᴗɵȢPpɸrRɹɻʁsʂʃTtƫUuᴜᴝʉɥɯɰʊvVʋʌwWxyzʐʑʒꝯᴥβγδθφχнნʕⵡ]
                [⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᴬᵃᴭᵆᵄᵅᶛᴮᵇᶜᶝᴰᵈᶞᴱᵉᴲᵊᵋᶟᵌᶠᴳᵍᶢˠʰᴴʱᴵⁱᶦᶤᶧᶥʲᴶᶨᶡᴷᵏˡᴸᶫᶪᶩᴹᵐᶬᴺⁿᶰᶮᶯᵑᴼᵒᵓᵔᵕᶱᴽᴾᵖᶲʳᴿʴʵʶˢᶳᶴᵀᵗᶵᵁᵘᶸᵙᶶᶣᵚᶭᶷᵛⱽᶹᶺʷᵂˣʸᶻᶼᶽᶾꝰᵜᵝᵞᵟᶿᵠᵡᵸჼˤⵯ];
   return $string;
}
```

And from [the *unisubs* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unisubs) is one for subscripts:

```perl
sub convert_to_subscripts (_) {
   my $string = $_[0];
   $string =~ tr[+−=()0123456789aeəhijklmnoprstuvxβγρφχ]
                [₊₋₌₍₎₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉ₐₑₔₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚᵣₛₜᵤᵥₓᵦᵧᵨᵩᵪ];
   return $string;
}
```

You just have to go the other way.

Another and simpler approach is simply to use the k-compat normalizations, which just return the base characters instead of their upper/lower versions.  I haven’t checked these to see that they are all the inverses of the functions above.  You can play with them using the [*nfkd*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/nfkd) and
[*nfkc*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/nfkc) scripts.

Comment: What do the |Q| and |QQ| lines mean in the linked script? Are those like HERE docs in bash?

Comment: @2ck Yes, that’s right.  The `|Q|` and `|QQ|` prefixes are there for readability; they get stripped off by the `deQ`, `deQQ`, and eventually the `dequeue` function (yes, that’s supposed to be an amusing set of names).  You might look for other scripts in the enclosing directory if you’re working with Unicode a bunch, especially *uniprops, unichars, uninames*. The CPAN [Unicode::Tussle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Tussle) suite will install them all for you, and has a bit of a description of each one.

Comment: NFKD works fine in the linked scripts but in my script spit out: â  I guess, I somewhere have to define my encodings properlz, if I type ₂ in my script I get â, if I read a text file in via ARGV[0] and then from $line I also get â.

Comment: @sseelenluft [Some of those scripts](http://training.perl.com/scripts/) expect you to have your `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable set to `S`, `SD`, or `SAD`. I wasn’t always good about that.

Comment: Even if I run my Perl script with: >PERL_UNICODE=S perl myscript.pl I still get â.

Comment: @sseelenluft Did you put `use utf8` in your script? Here, I’ve skimmed some of the Unicode recipes from the [4th edition of Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) here in this [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://training.perl.com/scripts/perlunicook.html) manpage that might help you.

Comment: I just did [put `use utf8` into my script] and NFKD works fine now for strings defined in the script itself (though not yet for ones read in from other files). But what works now even for files I read in is brpocock commment: `tr/₂₃/23/`, which could not be simpler.

Comment: @sseelenluft That will only work if you `use utf8`.  You could have derived that by inverting my original `tr`.